On how many circles will the roots of these constructed palindromic polynomials sit on?
The approximation to the Dirichlet eta function plus its conjugate:
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{a+i b-1}}\right) \zeta (a+b i)+\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{a-i b-1}}\right) \zeta (a-b i)=\frac{1}{1^{a-i b}}+\frac{1}{1^{a+i b}}-\frac{1}{2^{a+i b}}-\frac{1}{2^{a-i b}}+\frac{1}{3^{a+i b}}+\frac{1}{3^{a-i b}}- 
 \dots $$
can be written as:
$$=\frac{1}{\left(e^{\log(1)}\right)^{a-i b}}+\frac{1}{\left(e^{\log(1)}\right)^{a+i b}}-\frac{1}{\left(e^{\log(2)}\right)^{a+i b}}-\frac{1}{\left(e^{\log(2)}\right)^{a-i b}}+\frac{1}{\left(e^{\log(3)}\right)^{a+i b}}+\frac{1}{\left(e^{\log(3)}\right)^{a-i b}}-\dots \tag{1}$$
Letting the logarithms in $(1)$ be approximated by arbitrary numbers such as:
$$\log(1) \approx 0$$
$$\log(2) \approx \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\log(3) \approx \frac{5}{6}$$
one has:
$$\frac{1}{\left(e^{0}\right)^{a-i b}}+\frac{1}{\left(e^{0}\right)^{a+i b}}-\frac{1}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{a+i b}}-\frac{1}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{a-i b}}+\frac{1}{\left(e^{\frac{5}{6}}\right)^{a+i b}}+\frac{1}{\left(e^{\frac{5}{6}}\right)^{a-i b}} = 0 \tag{2}$$
Solving this truncated approximation for the imaginary part $b$ with the Mathematica 14 program:
Clear[log1, log2, log3, n, k, a, b]
log1 = 0
log2 = 1/2
log3 = 5/6
Reduce[1/(E^log1)^(a + b*I) + 1/(E^log1)^(a - b*I) - 
   1/(E^log2)^(a + b*I) - 1/(E^log2)^(a - b*I) + 
   1/(E^log3)^(a + b*I) + 1/(E^log3)^(a - b*I) == 0, b]

one gets the output:
C[1] \[Element] 
  Integers && (b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          1]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          2]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          3]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          4]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          5]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          6]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          7]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          8]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          9]]) || 
   b == -6  I  (2  I  \[Pi]  C[1] + 
       Log[Root[
         1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10 &,
          10]]))

or in Latex-ified form:
$$c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land \left(b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,1\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,2\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,3\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,4\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,5\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,6\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,7\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,8\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,9\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\lor b=-6 i \left(\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^{10}-\text{$\#$1}^8 e^{a/3}+2 \text{$\#$1}^5 e^{\frac{5 a}{6}}-\text{$\#$1}^2 e^{a/3}+1\&,10\right]\right)+2 i \pi  c_1\right)\right)$$
Because of the choice of the initial Dirichlet eta function plus its conjugate, the polynomial inside the root object is palindromic, which can be verified with this Mathematica program:
CoefficientList[
 1 - E^(a/3) #1^2 + 2 E^(5 a/6) #1^5 - E^(a/3) #1^8 + #1^10, #1]
Reverse[%]
%% == %

which returns the value True. Since palindromic polynomials have roots that sit on a circle in the complex plane, and since the logarithm of a set of points that form a circle in the complex plane, will sit on a vertical line in the complex plane, it means that the roots of $(2)$ will sit on a vertical line segment with the imaginary part modulo $\pi/2$.

But how many vertical lines or circles are the roots on? Infinitely many? Or 2 lines or circles?

This question is inspired by this paper: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/numbersoncircle.pdf by Keith Conrad.
